# How should I stick acoustic foams on the walls?

Tags: sound-proofing, acoustic, sound-deadening

I am a trained opera singer. I just moved into a single family house. I had a concern about the noise because the neighbors were not far away and I usually practice in the evening after work. Luckily, they cannot hear me from the inside, but they can from the sidewalks and driveways. When I placed my keyboard in the walk-in closet of the master bedroom and practiced, I could tell the significant reduction of the noise even in the sidewalks and driveways. With the acoustic foams covering all four walls of the walk-in closet, I believe I can make it practically noise-free.

Now, I do not want to apply the adhesive directly on my walls. There has to be something in between my walls and the acoustic foams. I think that foam boards can be a viable option. Just staple them on the walls and apply adhesive on it to stick the acoustic foams. When it is the time to sell the house, I can take the staples off to convert it back from a practice room to a walk-in closet.

What do you guys think? Do I have any other options better than foam boards?

Comment: It'll never be undetectable. Ask a sound engineer how decibels work.  Cutting sound by a factor of 100 only drops you 20db.  40db is the difference between a fighter jet (no noise abatement) and the latest 787 Dreamliners (state of the art noise abatement). End of the day they're still *jet engines*.

Comment: you could attach the foam to vertical strips of fabric that are hung near the ceiling and reach to the floor ..... string would also work ...... that would make the foam easily removable

Answer (score 1):

Spray adhesive the panels on sheets of plywood and hang them like pictures
. 
This is a great video, it's about home made sound absorption panels but there is a lot of useful information in it.

Watch "Anechoic Chamber - DIY Sound Absorption Panels" on YouTube
https://youtu.be/fqodnHxRJ7c